# Python ways to get around regex lookbehind zero width

Tags: python, regex

I wonder if there's a way to get around this issue. I have the string of this sort and would like to only extract out the University names.

My ideal pattern would be the below, but I know lookbehinds are zero-width.

```
idealpattern = (?<=\d+)\s+[A-Za-z ]{5,20}?(?=[A-Z][A-Z])
```

I also can just take the \d out of the lookbehind, and remove the numbers afterwards, but I was wondering if there's a way to eliminate this step with the lookbehind.

```
altpattern = \d+\s+[A-Za-z ]{5,20}?(?=[A-Z][A-Z])
```

What are common ways to overcome this issue?

> Business Officers and Commonfund Institute.    U.S. and Canadian
>   Institutions Listed by Fiscal Year 2013 Endowment Market Value and
>   Change* in Endowment Market Value from FY 2012 to FY 2013 *Note: The
>   change in market value does NOT represent the rate of return for the
>   institution\u2122s investments. Rather, the change in the market value
>   of an endowment from FY 2012 to FY 2013 reflects the net impact of:
>   1) withdrawals to fund institutional operations and capital expenses; 
>   2) the payment of endowment management and investment fees;     3)
>   additions from donor gifts and other contributions; and     4)
>   investment gains or losses.  Rank Institution State/ Province 2013
>   Endowment Funds ($000s) 2012 Endowment Funds ($000) *Change in Market
>   Value (%) 1 Harvard University MA 32,334,293 30,435,375 6.2 2 Yale
>   University CT 20,780,000 19,345,000 7.4 3 University of Texas System
>   TX 20,448,313 18,263,850 12.0 4 Stanford University CA 18,688,868
>   17,035,804 9.7 5 Princeton University NJ 18,200,433 16,954,128 7.4 6

Comment: Why not use `\d` instead of `\d+`? Practically, they do the same thing when you use them for a positive lookbehind.

Comment: Your maximum match length for the university name doesn't allow Princeton University to get captured, I'd suggest changing it from `{5,20}` to `{5,}`

Comment: I'll try that! and thanks for the tip. I did catch that maximum issue, but forgot to include that in this pattern. By the way, is there a hotkey to create <code> ? I know apple+k creates a code snippet, but i don't like how it indents it for text, which makes it hard to read.

Comment: In SO, you can precede a block of text with `>` to denote it as a "quote".  This is good formatting for a block of text like your example input.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need to use lookarounds?  This works for me:

```
re.findall(r"\d+\s+([A-Za-z ]{5,}?) [A-Z][A-Z]", subject)
```

output:

```
Harvard University
Yale University
University of Texas System
Stanford University
Princeton University
```

In other words, use a group to capture the part that really interests you.  Lookbehinds are a very late addition to regex feature lists, and this is not the problem they were meant to solve.

(Notice that I'm also taking advantage of the fact that Python's `findall()` method returns *only* the contents of capturing groups.  It's a nice feature when you're expecting it, but it tends to take people by surprise.)